# How to open a filename that the user entered?

Tags: c++, string, coding-style, iostream

```
    required.close();
    destined.close();
}
```

This program should ask the user to enter a filename and an output filename. The input filename should have a message that would be encrypted or decrypted, depends on the user's choice. The program should have 3 functions, one to check the file's existence, one to encrypt/decrypt each character and one to encrypt/decrypt the whole file.

Comment: A *minimal* example of your problem, please.

Comment: Try using an absolute path. It's probably related to your program having a different working directory to what you expect.

Comment: Is this a demonstration of how to write unreadable code - indentation please#

Comment: Calm down people, it's the first time I use this website!! Friendly much?!

Comment: I solved the problem and now the program is working, thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some errors and some things to change:

- in the `encChar` function this is wrong: `if (flag = true)`. You should use a comparison operator (`==`):

  ```
  `if (flag == true)`
  ```

  Someone prefers this form (comparison terms swapped):

  ```
  `if (true == flag)`
  ```

  because wrong assignments are detected.
- in the `encFile` function it should be:

  ```
  ofstream destined(outFile.c_str());
  ```

  It's a good idea to enable warnings (e.g. with GCC/CLANG use `-Wansi -Wall -Wextra`) so that unused variables/parameters are detected (in your case the `string outFile` input parameter).

Pay attention at Simple's advice (*Try using an absolute path. It's probably related to your program having a different working directory to what you expect*) and your program should work.

You could improve your code with some other changes:

- place variables in the narrowest scope possible and initialize variables in the declaration, e.g.

  ```
  ifstream required;
  required.open(inFile.c_str());
  ```

  should be

  ```
  ifstream required(inFile.c_str());
  ```

  (and check for error before using the stream).
- `using namespace std` [is considered a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).
- coding style and formatting are pretty arbitrary, but code is much easier to follow if you always use the same style.
- [don't use global variables](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/29130/is-this-code-with-global-variables-good-practice)

Comment: "ofstream destined(outFile.c_str());" where would it be placed?